# Using a data type with Constrained fields in place of a Constraint

Tags: haskell, operator-overloading, typeclass

**TL,DR;** *Extending* a constraint, ad-hoc...? My route is "forgetful", or un-equatable

Hello everyone, I'm currently trying my hand at making an overloaded function that could either take a constraint (in our case, `IsString`), or a data type with fields of the same constraint. Here is my code so far:

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    OverloadedStrings
  , FlexibleInstances
  , UndecidableInstances
  , InstanceSigs
  , TypeFamilies
#-}

import Data.Monoid

class Bar a where
  bar :: ( IsString b
         , Monoid b ) => a -> b

-- | This instance won't work.
instance ( IsString a
         , Monoid a ) => RelativeUrl a where
  bar :: ( IsString b
         , Monoid b
         , a ~ b ) => a -> b
  bar = id

-- | This is the data type "extending" @IsString@
data Foo a where
  Foo :: ( IsString a, Monoid a ) =>
         a -> Foo a

-- | This is where my dreams end :(
instance Bar (Foo a) where
  bar :: ( IsString b
         , Monoid b
         , a ~ b ) => a -> b
  bar (Foo a) = a
```

I realize that the instance signatures aren't kosher, and that's why (technically) this won't work, but is there any other way to do it? I'd ideally like all calls to `bar` be inferrable by the context - such that `bar "foo" :: IsString a => a`, without having to clamp-down the OverloadedString to an actual type.

Is there another way to achieve this? I'm open for crazy ideas :)

Comment: How would the compiler know which type's `bar` to call without "clamp[ing]-down the OverloadedString to an actual type"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Bar` class is about being able to convert to anything that `IsString`. I presume the `Monoid` instance is there for some sort of efficiency. We could give `Bar` and `bar` more illuminating names.

```
class ToStringPlus a where
  toStringPlus :: ( IsString b,
                    Monoid b ) => a -> b
```

You would like `bar "foo" :: IsString a => a`. With `OverloadedStrings` enabled `"foo" :: IsString a -> a`. You're asking how to convert a value that's already polymorphic over all instances of `IsString` to a value that's polymorphic over all instances of `IsString`. You don't need something like `toStringPlus "foo"` to do that, just use `"foo"`.

#### Hiding IsString

If you'd like to turn the type `forall a. IsString a => a` into a data type you can do so with a GADT. It's not at all useful, since the only possible value of the type `forall a. IsString a => a` is `fromString x` where `x :: String`. This type can hold exactly the same values that `String` can hold, with none of the utility `String` provides.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Data.String

data AString where
    AString :: (forall a. IsString a => a) -> AString

instance IsString AString where
    fromString x = AString (fromString x)

instance ToStringPlus AString where
    toStringPlus (AString a) = a
```

#### Something more useful

`AString` wasn't very useful because it could only hold the same values as a `String`. The `ToStringPlus` class allows converting to something using more than just `String`s, it also allows the `Monoid` operations of `mappend`, `mconcat`, and `mempty`. This means the type `forall a. (IsString a, Monoid a) => a` should be able to hold something different than just `String`s.

```
data MonoidalString where
    MonoidalString :: (forall a. (IsString a, Monoid a) => a) -> MonoidalString
```

`MonoidalString`s form a `Monoid`. Notice that `mconcat` and `mappend` can't be written in points-free style due to the rank N types.

```
instance Monoid MonoidalString where
    mempty = MonoidalString mempty
    (MonoidalString x) `mappend` (MonoidalString y) = MonoidalString (x `mappend` y)
    mconcat ms = MonoidalString (mconcat (map toStringPlus ms))
```

`MonoidalString`s can also be instances of `IsString` and `ToStringPlus` in the same manner as `AString` from the previous section.

```
instance IsString MonoidalString where
    fromString x = MonoidalString (fromString x)

instance ToStringPlus MonoidalString where
    toStringPlus (MonoidalString a) = a
```

This lets us give meaning to your request in a comment "I'm trying to convert something that's already polymorphic over all instances of `IsString` and any `Foo` [to something that's polymorphic...]". We can combine **using the `Monoid` operations** something that's already polymorphic over all instances of `IsString`, `"poly string"`, with a `MonoidalString` to get something that's polymorphic over all instances of `IsString` and `Monoid`.

Given something `existing :: MonoidalString` and `"poly string" :: IsString a => a` we can combine them with `mappend`.

```
                                      existing  :: MonoidalString
              "poly string"                     :: IsString a => a
              "poly string" `mappend` existing  :: MonoidalString
toStringPlus ("poly string" `mappend` existing) :: (Monoid b, IsString b) => b
```

We can make a small example program using this to show off all the features of `MonoidalString`

```
main = do
    let existing = ("MS" :: MonoidalString)
    putStr . toStringPlus $ mconcat ["poly string", mempty `mappend` " ", existing]
```

#### Bar again

If you want to make a function `bar` that accepts arguments of both types `forall a. Ctx a => a` and `D` you can do so as long as there is an `instance Ctx D`. The type of the function is then `D -> ...`. This works because a `forall a. Ctx a => a` can be used anywhere you need a `D`.

We can use this to write a `bar` for the last example.

```
bar :: (IsString a, Monoid a) => MonoidalString -> a
bar = toStringPlus
```

We can pass to `bar` a polymorphic string `"foo" :: IsString a => a`.

```
    "foo" :: IsString a => a
bar "foo"                    :: (Monoid a, IsString a) => a
```

We can also pass to bar a monomorphic `MonoidalString`, `existing :: MonoidalString`

```
    existing = ("MS" :: MonoidalString)
bar existing                            :: (Monoid a, IsString a) => a
```

Comment: See that's the thing. I'm trying to convert something that's already polymorphic over all instances of `IsString` __and__ any `Foo` [to something that's polymorphic...].


In my use case, `toStringPlus` will actually return an `m b` (where `m` is an instance of _another_ typeclass that gets inferred by the call site). If I am to type-coerce `m`'s inference, `toStringPlus` __must__ be able to handle both cases.

Comment: Also, the Monoid instance is just to give appending and emptyness of `IsString`s, to make my own generic pretty printers.

Comment: @AthanClark Perhaps you should ask how to solve your problem (describing your problem) rather than ask how to do something the compiler told you not to.

Comment: So you still have to refactor the constraint as a data type (to create bounds for the RankN `forall` declaration?). There is no way to make this instance solely from the context of `IsString`? Is there a way to infer `AString` without the constructor? And I'm sorry if you feel annoyed, but my issue is the compiler :)

Comment: @AthanClark I added something more useful that might be about what you are looking for.

Comment: @AthanClark No, there's no way to make an instance for either rank n or qualified types. If it did exist the syntax for it would probably be respectively `instance Ctx (forall a. a -> a) where ...` or `instance Ctx2 (forall a. Ctx => a) where ...`. These both result in the error "Illegal polymorphic or qualified type: ... In the instance declaration for ...".

Comment: Just as I expected. I wonder if that's the direction the language might go. It would be strange doing things like `instance IsString a => IsString a where`, but a proof-of-concept for reflexivity of instance would be nice. Thank you for all your help.